# how to get different offset in gnuplot labels

Tags: gnuplot, label

I found a very weird way to plot horizontal lines of discrete
values with labels on the left or on the right of the lines

I construct an input data file where:

- the values in the 1st column determine the amplitude of the horizontal lines
- the values in the 2nd column are repeated to draw the horizontal lines
- I put the labels in the 3rd and 4th column because, as you'll see below, this allows me to decide where to put the labels, at the left or at the right of the lines

```
+---+-----------+-------+--------+
| 3 | -0.178110 |   130 |        |
| 4 | -0.178110 |       |        |
| 5 | -0.178110 |       |        |
 empty line
| 3 | -0.185959 |   129 |        |
| 4 | -0.185959 |       |        |
| 5 | -0.185959 |       |        |
 empty line
| 3 | -0.188473 |       |        |
| 4 | -0.188473 |       |        |
| 5 | -0.188473 |   x   |    128 |
 empty line
| 3 | -0.208311 |   127 |        |
| 4 | -0.208311 |       |        |
| 5 | -0.208311 |       |        |
+---+-----------+-------+--------+
```

and then I used

plot 'input' u 1:($2*27.2114) w l notitle, \ 
 '' every 3 u 1:($2*27.2114):(x=3 ? $3 : 1/0) with labels font ",8" offset -2, 0 notitle, \ 
 '' u 1:($2*27.2114):(x=5 ? $4 : 1/0) with labels font ",8" offset 2, 0 notitle

to discriminate where to plot the label in the left or in.

I find it very odd, any tips to do it in a more elegant way?

Thanks in advance

Lorenzo

Comment: basically, what I have to do is to write some label at left, and some others on the right

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `every`? This allows to do it without any modification of the data file. Here an example with data generated on the fly by gnuplot:

```
plot [-1.5:1.5] "+" u (sin(10*$1)):1 ev 4 w p, "+" u (sin(10*$1)):1:1 ev 8 w labels offset 5,0, "+" u (sin(10*$1)):1:1 ev 8::4 w labels offset -5
```